# How to access detailed range against range equity?

Tags: software, range, equity

I am trying to find a software that would display a detailed version of equity.
let me explain.
Let's say I want to compute the equity of range 1: [AA,KK,QQ] against 
range 2 : [78s,TT,AKo]

If I input these range in any equity software such as equilab for example it will give me (almost) instantly the average equity of range 1 against range 2

But is there a way to access a detailed version aka 
three lines with:

- equity of AA against [78s,TT,AKo]
- equity of KK against [78s,TT,AKo]
- equity of QQ against [78s,TT,AKo]

I always thought that the average equity was computed using the numbers from each hand against the opponent range.

But is it really the case or are they using some kind of abstraction that makes it impossible to give a detailed version ?

thank you

Comment: Just plug in AA, KK, and QQ separate if you want the detail.

Comment: ok great but if im obviously talking about wider ranges , it was just an example

Comment: Then plug in more if you need more detail.   I fail to understand why you need the detail?   Equity versus a range is the number.

Answer (score 1):

Pokerstove is a good, opensource, free software that will give you these results (it can be found here: https://github.com/andrewprock/pokerstove). I am not sure if it will separate the hands out like you described, but maybe I can help you understand how the calculation is made by hand.

The equity of a range against a range is calculated by comparing the equity of each individual hand in one range to every hand in the other range. It then averages the equity out according to the number of possible combinations of each hand. A little tedious to make an example of, it is much easier to find the equity of a single hand vs a range by hand.

Pokerstove works differently though, it runs millions of simulations instead of brute force calculations. This makes it faster and very accurate.

Answer (score 0):

This average is simply computed by calculating all the equity from all combinations player 1 has against all the equity from all combination of player 2. Keep in mind that suited hands have 4, pocket pairs have 6 and non-suited hands have 12 combinations.

I don't know software that give you the details like you described, you can however just compute all seperate hands versus a particular range. So in this case AA vs 78s,TT,AKo and then replace AA with KK and repeat etc.